# Closing an excel workbook causes "print() on closed filehandle STDOUT" on subsequent `print`

Tags: perl

Perl version: v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

I am using `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` and I have been able to successfully create a new workbook, create worksheets, close workbook, etc.  However, after issuing close on the workbook, I can no longer print to STDOUT.

```
my $outFile = tmpnam();
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($outFile);
die "Error creating new Excel workbook: $!" unless defined $workbook;
...
$workbook = close() or die "Error closing Excel workbook: $!";

print "Trying to print something\n";
```

This is when I get the "print() on closed filehandle STDOUT" error message.

I've read and tried to use `IO::Scalar` method described by John McNamara to no avail.  How do I re-open STDOUT for output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$workbook = close()
```

This calls the global function `close` with no parameter, thereby closing `STDOUT` (or whatever the last selected filehandle was).

Did you mean this?

```
$workbook->close()
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really silly. Thanks for taking the time to point out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving STDOUT handler and then restoring it or printing directly to it: `open(my $stdout, ">&STDOUT") or die "Can't save stdout: $!";`